# How to take this conditional statement and rewrite it without if-then statements

Tags: algorithm, conditional-statements

In a project that I have for class the correct code for a specific method is:

```
if ((volume % 10) % 6 == 0)
       return 0;
 else if ((volume % 10) % 6 <= 4)
       return 1;
 else
       return 2;
```

However the teacher recently added a new condition stating that you are not allowed to use if statements. 
What I have so far is :

```
return ((volume % 10) % 6)/4 + ((volume % 10) % 6 % 4`);
```

however it doesnt work while ((volume % 10) % 6 % 4) is equal to 2.(it needs to be equal to 1)

I treid fixing it by dividing that by 2 but then when ((volume % 10) % 6 % 4) is equal to one it rounds down to 0

any ideas??

Comment: Just to be sure: The only operators you're allowed to use are `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `%` (modulo). Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
return ((k%10)%6 + 3)/4;
```

Comment: That's what I came up with for no branches at all. I don't know why you would want to do it, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense, for some reason I just couldn't think of it

Answer (score 2):

Heres how i would do it

theres a repeating pattern when you run your code from 0...n
the pattern is: 0,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,1

```
//initialize an array with the pattern. This is for javascript.
var a=[0,1,1,1,1,2,0,1,1,1];
return a[(volume%10)];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can rewrite it using ternary operator.  condition ? true expression :false expression. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

In below code false will be a new ternary operation.

```
 return  (volume % 10) % 6 == 0 ? 0 : ((volume % 10) % 6 
    <= 4 ? 1 : 2 );
```

Comment: This would simply hide the `if...else`

Comment: @Barranka Isn't what OP requested ? .Not to use if else.

Comment: @Hakunamatatata The conditional is still there, you're simply rewriting it. The expression written by the OP makes clear (to me at least) that the objective is to remove any conditional evaluation

Answer (score -1):

Hate to use a loophole, but will

```
return ((volume % 10 ) % 6 == 0 :0 ? <the sub expressions>)
```

work?